# Removing unreferenced objects from remote

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-push

I'm wondering if a remote `git` repo does (or should do) automatic delete of unreferenced file objects (and also trees) once it received a `push` from local, after rebasing local and skipping some commits that introduced those files and also these commits deleted those files. Since these skipped commits are no longer in the history chain of commits it's logical that remote delete these objects as they are now not part of any commit in the history. This graph may explain it:

This is the history before `rebase --onto`

```
 * b5b7c142 after-deleting offending-file
 * db759b06 deleted offending-file
 * 59a9440a added offending-file
 * 933729b1 before-adding-offending-file
```

which was pushed to the remote before I regret it. But here comes the attempt to fix it...

`rebase --onto 933729b1 db759b06`

which effectively reconstructs commit  `b5b7c142 after-deleting offending-file`

to have a different parent: `933729b1 before-adding-offending-file` and leaving the middle two commits simply ignored.

This is how it looks after the rebase above: (please note that first commit SHA1 changed because we changed parent)

```
* 17c95f49 after-deleting offending-file
| * db759b06 deleted offending-file
| * 59a9440a added offending-file
| /
* 933729b1 before-adding-offending-file
```

and it's looking ok for a history on local and that file object still exists in .git/objects, it's a part of some commits that are here still. Now what happens if I pushed now to the remote? Will it delete that file object in `.git/objects` on github as it's now not part of any commit/tree? And if not, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub may or may not delete the unreachable commit and file some time in the future.  It's up to them.

A normal everyday Git repository—one you control, for instance—will generally drop the unreferenced commit entirely when `git gc` runs.  For that to happen, though, first *all* references have to go away.  Using `git rebase` leaves several references behind, on purpose:

- There is an entry in the `HEAD` reflog (viewable with `git reflog`).
- There is an entry in the branch reflog (viewable with `git reflog branch`).
- There is a reference in `ORIG_HEAD`.

The last one will be overwritten with the next operation that saves the previous `HEAD` value in `ORIG_HEAD`.  The other two will eventually be dropped due to reflog entry expiration.  Each reflog entry is timestamped, and is "live" until the *current* time is more than the expiration time added to the entry's timestamp.  Another of `git gc`'s functions is to check for expired entries, which it will delete.  The expiration time is under your control, and is both 30 days and 90 days by default.  This part is confusing (how can it be *both?*) but is not really relevant to the *GitHub* variant because they don't use the reflogs like this: the point is that the references have to be *really gone*, which takes time, and this part is true for GitHub as well.

Once the references are *really gone*, a `git gc` would discard the internal objects that hold the unwanted commit and file, *provided* that they're not in a *kept pack*.  Kept packs are something you have to create on your own—Git doesn't do this itself—so if you're not doing that, you personally won't encounter this.

The main issue you'll have with GitHub is that you don't know when *they* will scrub their last reference, nor when they will subsequently run a `git gc` that will discard the object—*plus*, they add special refs for pull requests, issues, and other items, which can keep objects alive indefinitely.  The upshot of all of this is that you cannot predict when or even whether some file will disappear from GitHub.

Note that you *can* contact GitHub support and get them to do a manual scrub.  Of course, by then, any number of people could have obtained this file, so if there's any sensitive data in it, consider it to be well-known to the black-hat hacker community by now.

Comment: The next question is different of the original one but I'm not sure if it should be a separate thread because the original question above PLUS your answer would be needed there for explaining the situation. If my remote is a fork from upstream, how does GitHub process unreferenced object when a pull request approval and then merge? Will it transfer all the commits including those unreachable, along with unreferenced objects to the upstream that I forked from, increasing the size of the upstream repo?

Comment: update, further discussion about `git prune` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988200/git-push-and-unreferenced-objects

Comment: Your first question (about how GitHub handles forked repositories) gets into complicated and I think proprietary information: GitHub don't say precisely how they manage all of this. I'm pretty sure, based on other information I've read elsewhere, that GitHub use Git's "alternates" code to literally share object and pack access, but to make this work well, they must have made some changes to this code. The short version of all of this is to say "I don't know". :-) I'll look at the prune link now...